# Constructor cannot access private properties of its own class?

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, constructor

I'm trying to write a class that create integral object. However, the constructor is not working properly. It cannot set the integral.value to correct value when GetAccess is set to private or protected. Only when GetAccess is set to public, then it works. WHY??

Here's the code.

```
classdef nintegral
    properties(GetAccess=private, SetAccess=private)
       value
    end

    methods
       function v = nintegral(j) %class constructor
         if isa(j,'pf')==0
            disp('Function object is not a piecewise function')

         else
            v.value = integral(@(x) j.p1(1)*x.^2 + j.p1(2)*x + j.p1(3),j.r1(1),j.r1(2)) + integral(@(x) j.p2(1)*x.^2 + j.p2(2)*x + j.p2(3),j.r2(1),j.r2(2));
        end

    end

end
```

end

Here's the pf class.

```
 classdef pf
  properties(GetAccess=public,SetAccess=private)
    r1=[-1,0]; %range 1
    r2=[0,1]; %range 2
    p1=[1,1,1]; %polynomial 1
    p2=[1,1,1];  %polynomial 2       
  end

methods
    function j=pf(r1,p1,r2,p2) % class constructor
        if r1(2)>r2(1)
            disp('ERROR FUNCTION DEFINITION: Overlaping range')

        else
            j.r1=r1;
            j.r2=r2;
            j.p1=p1;
            j.p2=p2;
        end

    end

    function v=eval(j,x)
        if x<j.r1(1) | x>j.r2(2)
            disp('Error: Out of Range')
        else
            if x>j.r1(1) & x<=j.r1(2)
                v=polyval(j.p1,x);
            else
                v=polyval(j.p2,x);
            end

        end

    end

end
```

end

Comment: How do you check the value ? If you check it outside the constructor then it is normal ...

Comment: Got a function to check? Can you show the code where you check the value?

Comment: Hi Krisdestruction do you mean you want an pf object? let me share with you.

Comment: @Ratbert please explain a bit. I'm new to OOP. What do you mean by check the value outside the constructor? What I see is that I try to pass an pf object to the nintegral constructor, perform some calculation then set the result to nintegral.value.

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I create pf and then pass it to nintegral. You missed "end" statements while copying your code though.

Comment: Hi Navan, I already modified this code to get it running. I dont understand why if GetAccess=private, the constructor fail to properly initialize the object.